# Spring with Thymeleaf - Display Array of Roles in UI

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm having some learning pains trying to get user roles to display in my UI. The UI is `Thymeleaf`.

I have the following which does display the first item in the array:

```
<tr th:each="appuser: ${appuser}">
    <td th:text="${appuser.id}"></td>
    <td th:text="${appuser.firstName}" />
    <td th:text="${appuser.lastName}" />
    <td th:text="${appuser.email}" />
    <td th:text="${appuser.roles[0].name}" />
    <td></td>
    <td><a class="btn btn-primary"
        th:href="@{/edit/{id}(id=${appuser.id})}">Edit</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The array of user roles is where I'm having some issue. How would I display the array in a foreach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [for-each](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-arrays#2-iteration) construction

```
<td>
  <a th:each="role: ${appuser.roles}" th:text="${role.name}"></a>
</td>
```

Example:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a>name1</a><a>name2</a><a>name3</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```